# iOS Automation execution doesn't start, Fails at xcodebuild error 70

Tags: appium-ios, xcode15

While executing iOS Automation with Robot Framework + Appium, it throws xcodebuild error code 70. Please find attached error for reference:
`WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 70 xcodebuild error message: . Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.`

Here is setup I am using:
Mac OS version: 14.0
XCode version: 15.0.1
Appium version: 2.2.0
Node version: 18.13.0
Appium Plugins

- execute-driver@3.0.1
- relaxed-caps@1.0.0-beta.14
- images@2.0.1

Appium Drivers

- uiautomator2@2.12.1
- xcuitest@5.7.0

Let me know if more information is needed. Thanks in Advance

I tried all the latest versions that has been mentioned in description. XCode provisioning profile is also proper

Comment: No solution yet :(
Same observation with XCode 15.1 RC build

Comment: Still, there is an issue with the latest versions below:

Mac OS version: 14.2.1
XCode version: 15.1
Appium version: 2.3.0
Node version: 18.13.0

Appium Plugins:
execute-driver@3.0.1
relaxed-caps@1.0.0-beta.14
images@2.0.1

Appium Drivers:
uiautomator2@2.34.1
xcuitest@5.12.2